# How to pass control.ClientId to onlcick function

Tags: asp.net

At the moment i'm hard coding the clientId into my control markup like so

```
OnClientClick="(function(){document.getElementById('clientIdOfTheControl').value='Loading...';})();"
```

is there anyway to do this without knowing the `clientIdOfTheControl` when writing the markup?

Answer (score 0):

You could use codebehind:

```
control.OnClientClick = "(function(){document.getElementById('" + control.ClientID +"').value='Loading...';})();";
```

Comment: Nice but it makes more sense in my case to place it in my markup